# Can I cut a hole in the brick to install a through the wall air conditioner in a basement?

Tags: basement, air-conditioning, brick

I am looking to install a through the wall air conditioner in the basement. I don't want to block the one window. There is already a window in the brick. I don't know if there is any kind of structural issue with cutting and framing in the air conditioner.

Here is the air conditioner sleeve. [LG AXSVA1](http://www.lg.com/us/appliance-accessories/lg-AXSVA1-wall-sleeve)

[image: Interior location for A/C]
[image: Exterior location for A/C]
Approximate location in red dashes.

Comment: Are You gonna cut all the rectangular shape out? I mean, get rid all the bricks and You are asking if this is ok? If not, what are the desired hole dimensions? And where?

Comment: Related; keyword *lintel*: [Making window in concrete foundation](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26589/what-should-i-consider-when-cutting-making-window-in-concrete-foundation)

Comment: Serious structural issues. You need an architect or engineer to review.

Comment: I'm looking to install a through the wall sleeve and air conditioner. The dimensions of the sleeve are 25 7/8" width and 15 7/32 height.

Comment: This is serious. The issue is that if you were building this new with an opening in it, you would be installing a lintel or building an arch, or leaving it open to the top and using jack studs and a header--an appropriate header of *some* kind--to support the load above the opening and transfer that load to the brick on either side. If you just cut a hole in a plain brick wall after it's built, you have none of that support. In this case, you have the weight of a house sitting on the brick. You do need an engineer.

Comment: This is the kind of response i'm looking for. I don't plan on just knocking a hole in the bricks myself but wanted to know is it possible and what should be considered. If the hole can be made,  framed and supported with the lintel that is what i need to know. It is possible. but definitely above my pay grade.

Comment: You sound reasonable, Ed!  The reference by @Mazura to cutting a groove part-way through to insert a steal lintel, then finishing the groove from the other side to finish inserting the lintel, then cutting the hole underneath narrower than the lintel probably *is* real similar to what will happen in practice.

Comment: This is a perfect application for a mini-split AC unit. That would allow you to install the AC exactly where you want it, and just drill a small hole through the wall to connect the two parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cutting a hole in your foundation almost always requires an engineer, and is almost never a do-it-yourself project.

You'll need an engineer, to tell you how to carry the load around the opening. And you'll likely need tools and knowledge you don't have, to actually cut the hole.

Comment: +1 Totally agree. This must be done with accordance to codes and with all needed structure computation. The problem is same as for inserting a window into a wall. You also need a large hole here after all.

Answer (score 1):

Comment from:
[What should I consider when cutting/making a window in a concrete foundation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26589/what-should-i-consider-when-cutting-making-window-in-concrete-foundation)

> I wouldn't do this without an **L shaped metal lintel** on the inside to support the load above and also prevent crack/total failure of the veneer. My only thought would be to cut the hole for the window then immediately move to the interior of the home and cut a groove on the inside of this new window so that lintel can slide into the groove and support the very top of the window. The bottom of the window should be sloped outward as well to prevent rain from puddling outside the window too. –  [TugboatCaptain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/12436/tugboatcaptain)